# Tornado server: enable CORS requests

Tags: cors, tornado

I have a simple tornado server which has the class:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def set_default_headers(self):
        print "setting headers!!!"
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

When a regular (no CORS) request is made, the server answers as expected, including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. But when I make a post request coming from different domain (using `jQuery.post`), the response is 404 and an error is displayed:  "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev-machine:8090/handshake. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8090' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404."

Can you tell if I miss something? (another header/other configuration/anything else)

Comment: that `pass` there is superfluous/wrong.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your code is missing preflight, the `OPTIONS` request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS:

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard works by adding new HTTP
> headers that allow servers to describe the set of origins that are
> permitted to read that information using a web browser.  Additionally,
> for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on user data (in
> particular, for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with
> certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers
> "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server
> with an HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from
> the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request
> method.  Servers can also notify clients whether "credentials"
> (including Cookies and HTTP Authentication data) should be sent with
> requests.

To implement preflight handler simply add options handler with the same headers and no body.

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def set_default_headers(self):
        print "setting headers!!!"
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')

    def post(self):
        self.write('some post')

    def get(self):
        self.write('some get')

    def options(self, *args):
        # no body
        # `*args` is for route with `path arguments` supports
        self.set_status(204)
        self.finish()
```

**edit**

I've added `x-requested-with` header to allowed list. And here is simple jquery sample:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "http://some_tornado/api",
   type: "POST",
   crossDomain: true,
   data: 'some_data',
   success: function (response) {
     alert(response);
   },
   error: function (xhr, status) {
     alert("error");
   }
 });
```

And some really good article about cors - http://dev.housetrip.com/2014/04/17/unleash-your-ajax-requests-with-cors/

Comment: does it mean I should change my JS post and create an "options" request?

Comment: I've added samples. Basically preflight is done by browser under the hood.

Comment: Yeah, I found it after posted this comment. Thank you, it was really helpful!

Comment: When I use ``self.get_argument`` in options or get/post method in tornado I can hardly get any argument value.

Comment: what would be the XMLHttpRequest version of `crossDomain: true` ?

Comment: Wow ! genius reply. Solved my issue

Comment: Tornado content-type support is limited: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415555/tornado-post-request-missing-argument

Comment: In my case everything was good except one little detail: 

`self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")`

with this last bit of information it worked.

Answer (score 9):

The answer by kwarunek led me to the solution for my trouble with the PUT and the DELETE request. The only thing is, that the solution is over-appropriate for the example with GET and POST. In this case the line

```
self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

is actually sufficient (if the browser doesn't block CORS before all). It is though most relevant for the PUT and DELETE requests. What happens here on the network level can be slightly more complex than in the GET/POST case.

"If the request is a "non-simple" request, the browser first sends a data-less "preflight" OPTIONS request, to verify that the server will accept the request. A request is non-simple when using an HTTP verb other than GET or POST (e.g. PUT, DELETE)." [cf. non-simple requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work/10636765#10636765)

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def set_default_headers(self):
        print("setting headers!!!")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', ' PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')

    def options(self):
        # no body
        self.set_status(204)
        self.finish()
```

Now all handlers that inherit from `BaseHandler` are fully CORS-capable:

```
class MyHandler(BaseHandler):

    def put(self):
        self.write('some post')

    def delete(self):
        self.write('some get')
```

Answer (score 4):

Even with the previous answers I still got the following CORS error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://127.0.0.1:9999/home?message=Input%20to%20API.. (Reason: missing
>   token ‘access-control-allow-origin’ in CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

and the ***solution*** is to also allow the headers:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def set_default_headers(self):
        print("setting headers!!!")
        self.set_header("access-control-allow-origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        # HEADERS!
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access-control-allow-origin,authorization,content-type") 

    def options(self):
        # no body
        self.set_status(204)
        self.finish()
```

Comment: Worked for me with:
self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")

Comment: thanks for showing that we can keep multiple values in Access-Control-Allow-Headers by separating them with comma.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
def set_default_headers(self):
    self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type")
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT')
```

Comment: This works. And the fact that it took me so long to find a solution to this completely trivial bs is just unbelievable. Also had   to define `def options(self):`

Answer (score 0):

Some of the existing answer are working, but they are adding unnecessary headers. The default header is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and the rest of the `Access-Control-*` headers only need to be set for the [preflight](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/#preflight-requests) (`OPTIONS`) request.

```
class CorsHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    def options(self, *args):
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Request-Credentials", "true")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network", "true")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
        self.set_status(204)  # No Content
```

You inherit from the `CorsHandler` to enable CORS for your other handlers.

**Warning**: The `*` and `true` values are **insecure** and you should set them to match your environment.

Relevant reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
- https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/
- https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66555660