# Python Tornado - CORS PUT

Tags: python, ajax, cors, tornado

I am facing a problem with Tornado. I have an API endpoint for PUT HTTP Method in Tornado. I also have a web application that sends the request to this API with jQuery and AJAX, but always I get a 405 response because the request is going as HTTP Method OPTIONS. 
I understand the way it works and I did configured my Tornado Server to allow it. But even so I having this situation.
Can someone help me?

There is my server code:

```
class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-   revalidate, max-age=0')
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `options` handler that just sends the headers with no body:

```
def options(self):
    # no body
    self.set_status(204)
    self.finish()
```

See [Tornado server: enable CORS requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254742/tornado-server-enable-cors-requests/35259440#35259440) for a complete code snippet.

Or else just install [the `tornado-cors` package](https://github.com/globocom/tornado-cors):

```
pip install tornado-cors
```

That will add the necessary handlers for you, and ensure the right response headers get sent.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't define put method return 405

```
class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def put(self):
        self.set_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0')
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
```

> [I 170205 04:56:35 web:1971] 200 PUT

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
This snippet is for my parent class which one I inherit in other handlers.
So I have the implementation of the PUT Method in my specific handler :)