# CORS in python tornado only send option request

Tags: python, cors, httprequest, tornado

First of all I've read this question:
[Tornado server: enable CORS requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254742/tornado-server-enable-cors-requests/35259440)
What I did is:

```
class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    def set_default_headers(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS")
```

And also an option method:

```
def options(self):
    self.set_status(204)
    self.finish()
```

And in my handler:

```
class AmirTest(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.write('You have requested get method!')

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.write('You have requested post method!')

    def put(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.write('You have requested put method!')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.write('You have requested delete method!')
```

This is how I request:

```
function del(){
    $.rest.put(
        "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7777/amir_test",
        {user: "A",pass: "b"}, 
        function (data) {console.log(data);}
    );
}
```

The problem is when I made a request this url, in the network tab of inspector there is only an option and no put request. what should I do?

[image: Loot at the inspect element]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Access-Control-Allow` headers alone only work for `GET` (and some `POST`) requests. For other methods, the `OPTIONS` request is mandatory. You must implement `options()` as shown in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: I have done it but forgot to copy here, Question updated but the same results! what now?

Comment: Your `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` needs to include all the methods you support (including PUT and DELETE in this case)