# CORS error on request to localhost dev server from remote site

Tags: google-chrome, cors, webpack-dev-server, preflight, private-network-access

On Friday I had a working dev environment. On Monday I had a broken one. I encountered this error message in the Chrome dev-tools console for all my assets:

> Access to CSS stylesheet at 'http://localhost:8080/build/app.css' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private adress space `local`.

Is there any quick fix for this? I tried setting access-control-allow-origin in my webpack `devServer.headers` config to no avail:

```
config.devServer.headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
}
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**Original Answer**

I finally found the answer, in this [RFC about CORS-RFC1918](https://web.dev/cors-rfc1918-feedback/) from a Chrome-team member. To sum it up, Chrome has implemented [CORS-RFC1918](https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/), which prevents public network resources from requesting private-network resources - unless the public-network resource is secure (HTTPS) and the private-network resource provides appropriate (yet-undefined) CORS headers.

There's also a Chrome flag you can change to disable the new behavior for now:
`chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests`

Disabling that flag does mean you're re-opening the security hole that Chrome's new behavior is meant to close.

---

**Update 2021**: A few months after I posted this question, the flag I referenced in my original answer was removed, and instead of disabling a security feature I was forced to solve the problem more satisfactorily by serving assets over HTTPS.

**Update 2022**: Chrome 98 is out, and it introduces support for [*Preflight requests*](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/). According to the announcement, failed requests are supposed to produce a warning and have no other effect, but in my case they are full errors that break my development sites. So I had to add middleware to teach `webpack-dev-server` how to serve preflight requests.

[Private Network Access](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-update/) (formerly CORS-RFC1918) is a specification that forbids requests from less private network resources to more private network resources. Like HTTP to HTTPS, or a remote host to localhost.

The ultimate solution was to add a self-signed certificate and middleware which enabled requests from my remote dev server to my localhost `webpack-dev-server` for assets.

#### Generate certificates

```sh
cd path/to/.ssl
npx mkcert create-cert
```

#### Configure `webpack-dev-server` to use certificates and serve preflight requests

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    https: {
      key: readFileSync("./.ssl/cert.key"),
      cert: readFileSync("./.ssl/cert.crt"),
      cacert: readFileSync("./.ssl/ca.crt"),
    },

    allowedHosts: ".example.dev", // should match host in origin below
    setupMiddlewares(middlewares, devServer) {
      // Serve OPTIONS requests
      devServer.app.options('*', (req, res) => {
        // Only serve if request has expected origin header
        if (/^https:\/\/example\.dev$/.test(req.headers.origin)) {
          res.set({
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network": "true",
            // Using * results in error if request includes credentials
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": req.headers.origin,
          })

          res.sendStatus(200)
        }
      }

      return middlewares
    }
  }
}
```

#### Trust certificates

1. Right click `ca.crt` in Windows Explorer and select *Install Certificate*
2. Select *Current User*.
3. Choose *Place all certificates in the following store*, then *Browse...*, and select *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*.
4. Finish.

##### Firefox-specific instructions

Firefox doesn't *respect your authoritah!* by default. Configure it to do so with these steps:

1. Type `about:config` into the address bar
2. Search for `security.enterprise_roots.enabled`
3. Toggle the setting to `true`

Comment: I would love to see the exact rules for this. I've got hit by this too, but the "private" server was the web server including the resource (it was on a publicly-allocated IP block but not externally routable), and the resource was a `bootstrap.js` hosted on cloudflare. My understanding is that it should block resources loaded from "more private" endpoints and I hardly see how couldflate could be considered more private in this regard. Could it be considering the proxy address rather than the DNS resolution for the target?

Comment: Is your private server http and cloudflare https?

Comment: Yes indeed and neither are under my control... The error message lacks clarity imho, so apparently they consider an https connection more private than an http connection. Is that consideration taking priority over private vs. public IP addresses though? Remember my "private" host is still using a public ip block, just not routable externally. Those are two valid yet different definitions of "private".

Comment: Self-Signed-Cert is no solution, the browser does not accept those out of the box.  Dummy Extranet-Domain-Cert (via some Domain on Internet re-used for the Extranet-Server) is no solution, the Extranet-Server has a (very fixed, very hardcoded) IP (only accessible via VPN).  Creating my own CA in the browser is even more insecure, as I then have to protect this CA key, which is complete overkill for such a simple problem.  Hence the Extranet ressource must stay `http://IP`.  But it still must be able to access some well defined `http://127.*` (which are secured against abuse).  Checkmate?

Comment: @tino regarding self-signed certs, in Windows you can right click a `.crt` file, select _Install Certificate_, and install it to _Trusted Root Certification Authorities_.
In Firefox, you then have to go to `about:config` and set `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` to `true`. All other browsers accept your trusted authorities automatically in my experience. You may have to restart.

Comment: @tino I updated my answer to include the steps for generating the certs and getting your browsers to trust them

Comment: @tvanc Thanks for the idea, but this does not help me.  As I wrote, browsers should accept this out-of-the-box, so installing a Cert is a no-go as this contradicts the paradigm out-of-the-box.  And Windows?  Web!  Hence all OS please (which are capable to run an app)!  Think of BYOD, WiFi and `http://1.1/` (where 1.0.0.1 is *not* routed to Internet)

Comment: @tvanc And BTW, **as you noted**, I hope that adding the header `Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network` to the localhost webservice will do the trick.  But https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/ still is a draft ..

Comment: My question was about using `webpack-dev-server` in development environments, where self-signed and manually-installed certificates are an acceptible solution. For production it's less likely that you would have reason to request `localhost` resources from a remote site, and you would use traditional signed SSL certificates.

Comment: Are Access-Control-Request-Private-Network and Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network already supported ? Where can I check this ?

Comment: @musmus https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/#headers

Comment: @tvanc not sure why you referred me to this link there is no info in there about when will they be added, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 65):

just a Chrome client way to ignore this warning and make assets accessable:

1: go to `chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests`

2: set **`Block insecure private network requests`** to Disabled

Note: this just works fine when you're in your own computer or your dev environment

[image]

Comment: This expose to any real security risk?

Comment: 2022 doesnt work anymore :/

Comment: 28-Sep-2022 still it is working

Comment: 2-Dec-2022 -> Not Working -> Chrome Version: 108.0.5359.72  -> Temporary work around  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74651311/1019435

Comment: jan-2023 and still working

Comment: 28-Aug-2023 Working again.

Comment: 20-Oct-2023 -> Not Working -> Brave 1.59.120 Chromium: 118.0.5993.88 (Official Build) arm64

Answer (score 9):

I was able to allow requests from localhost to localhost with setting one new server header to preflight and usual requests:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network: true
```

Source:
https://web.dev/cors-rfc1918-feedback/#step-2:-sending-preflight-requests-with-a-special-header

Comment: Showing how or where you set this header would make this answer more useful.

Comment: I already have added this, but it does not work.  Probably because the external site (which I do not control) is HTTP only, so Chrome does not even do preflight in my case.  (The problem is not the script but the sitescript injected by some extension.  So I have to route the request via background scripts.  Sigh.)

Answer (score 2):

While it is a good thing that Chrome now protects users from cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks targeting routers and other devices on private networks, it also means that legitimate applications, namely business applications, that rely on cross-site requests to resources on private networks are negatively affected and need to be changed. In my company, we maintain a web application that is exposed publicly through HTTPs and calls a web service on label printers on the client's private network. We ended up developing a proxy that accepts web service requests on a public and secure endpoint, and forwards them to the web service on the private network. We are now making this proxy available for others to use: https://p2prox.io/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this subject, since I had the same problem with a webserver instance in our local network. This is not necessarily a complex problem. It may happen, e.g. if you include javascript libraries from public resources, such as vue.js or node.js. To avoid this in a local network, store a copy of the library on your local server and reference it in your web pages. E.g. instead of using:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.31/vue.global.min.js"></script>
```

use

```
<script src="./lib/vue.global.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Temporary work around.**

In **Windows command prompt** run the below command and **restart** the chrome.

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome /t REG_DWORD /v InsecurePrivateNetworkRequestsAllowed /d 1 /f
```

The above command will create the following entry in windows registry.

[image]

**Reference:**

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-update/

https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#InsecurePrivateNetworkRequestsAllowed

Answer (score 1):

**December 2022 update**

I think they renamed the flag ...

- Try *chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost*
- Set to Enabled
- Restart Chrome

Answer (score 0):

> Access to CSS stylesheet at 'http://sub.domain.com/font/Sahel.css'
> from origin 'http://sub.domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in
> more-private address space `private`.

I'm developing a web-base system for the company I work in, and we have set up the dns and domain to access the system locally while we are inside the company and access it through internet while we are not there. no https cer was installed ever.

Above quote shows up from time to time and refers to same domain as one in a private level and the other as a less private! and it will be fixed by <kbd>Ctrl + F5</kbd>. so ridiculous!

In my case, adding a dynamic version using ?v=time() at the end of ALL OF MY LOCAL LINKS fixed my problem, but it costs downloading all scripts, css, fonts everytime user load the page!