# Webpack dev server sockjs-node returns 404 error

Tags: webpack-dev-server, vue-cli, webpack-hmr

I am running a simple Vue app with webpack that I created with the vue-cli. When I run the dev server wtih `npm run serve`, it shows several errors in the client console when using `sockjs-node`. I believe this module is used by webpack for hot reloading (HMR).

The first error is:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.4:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1615330207390' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I can solve this in two ways by editing the `devServer` in my `vue.config.js`. The first method is by setting `public: 'localhost:8080'`; and the second is by setting `headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://192.168.1.4:8080', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'}`.

In both cases, I then see the following two errors:

> POST http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/690/qvgqwbdo/xhr_streaming?t=1615330686134 404 (Not Found)

> GET http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/690/zympwfsc/eventsource 404 (Not Found)

How do I resolve these errors so that the hot reloader will connect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69464875/1330193 this answer helped me to fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function I set to `devServer.before` in my `vue.config.js` file, I created my own websockets using Socket.io on the same port as my devSever. When the function returned, the devServer could not use that port for websockets, so it failed to launch sockjs-node. Therefore, when the frontend client tried to connect to the devServer, the requests were going to my sockets, instead of the devServer sockets, and it was ignoring them. Hence the 404 errors.

Here is my original code:

```js
// server.js
const { createServer } = require('http')
const io = require('socket.io')
const addSocketEvents = require('./socket-api')

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080

module.exports = {
    port,
    configure(app) {
        // `app` is an instance of express

        // add the websockets
        const httpServer = createServer(app)
        socket = io(httpServer, {
            path: '/socket-api'
        })
        addSocketEvents(socket)

        // starts the server
        // cannot use app.listen() because that will not start the websockets
        httpServer.listen(port)
    }
}
```

```js
// vue.config.js
const { port, configure } = require('./server')

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        before: configure,
        public: `localhost:${port}`,
    },
}
```

To fix this issue, I needed to allow the devServer to use the original port for sockjs-node, and launch my sockets on a different port. However, because I need to use the same port in production (due to restrictions by my current hosting provider), I only want my sockets to use a different port when running the devServer. To do this, I simply created a different httpServer and launched it on a different port, then created a proxy in the devServer config for that port. In my `configure` function, I just check to see if it is running in dev or prod, and act accordingly.

My production server is a simple `express` instance which calls the same `configure` function after it is created. This allows me to put all my startup code in one place.

Here is my new code:

```js
// server.js
const { createServer } = require('http')
const io = require('socket.io')
const addSocketEvents = require('./socket-api')

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
const proxyPort = 8081

module.exports = {
    port,
    proxyPort,
    configure(app) {
        // `app` is an instance of express

        // add the websockets
        let httpServer, socketPort
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
            httpServer = createServer()
            socketPort = proxyPort
        } else {
            httpServer = createServer(app)
            socketPort = port
        }

        // adds the socket-api to be used via websockets
        socket = io(httpServer, {
            path: '/socket-api'
        })
        addSocketEvents(socket)
        
        // starts the server
        httpServer.listen(socketPort)
    }
}
```

```js
// vue.config.js
const { port, configure } = require('./server')

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        before: configure,
        public: `localhost:${port}`,
        proxy: {
            '/socket-api': {
                target: `http://localhost:${proxyPort}`,
                ws: true
            }
        }
    },
}
```