# Getting Cors Policy Error local host not able to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, cors, suitecommerce

I'm receiving this when I'm running local host Since I'm working on Net SuiteCommerce Advanced E-commerce webstore but from last two days I'm getting this error. I've searched about it on Stackoverflow and some other various websites but not got any satisfactory solution so I'm posting it in here.

Tried with downloading Cors extension and activated but it didn't work. And local host is working fine other than Google chrome.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7777/who/shopping' from origin 'http://www.cricketsca.ml' has been blocked by CORS policy:
```

The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.

**shopping-local.ssp:1 Access to resource at 'http://localhost:7777/extensions/J_J/JJ_Base_Theme/3.0.2/img/favicon.ico' from origin 'http://www.cricketsca.ml' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome CORS error on request to localhost dev server from remote site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534759/chrome-cors-error-on-request-to-localhost-dev-server-from-remote-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because of [recent Google Chrome update](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-update/). There were some similar troubles before, but with some [work-arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69311082/getting-cors-policy-error-local-host-not-able-to-run). For now you can try another browser (Firefox, for example).