# CefSharp CORS error on request to localhost: request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local

Tags: c#, cors, chromium, cefsharp, private-network-access

I am building a web app with the following architecture:

1. remote server
2. CefSharp to render pages coming from the remote server
3. local server to communicate the app with a serial port

But when I make requests from the client to the local server I get some CORS errors

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3100/connection' from origin
> 'http://cloud.tissuelabs.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
> request client is not a secure context and the resource is in
> more-private address space `local`

so I added headers to the local server response

```
{
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *,
 Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network: true
}
```

it was working on firefox, but not on chrome nor on cefsharp. Then, I found this answer on stackoverflow ([Chrome CORS error on request to localhost dev server from remote site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534759/chrome-cors-error-on-request-to-localhost-dev-server-from-remote-site)) that suggested to disable chrome`s flag

```
chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests
```

it worked on chrome, but I don`t know how to disable this flag on cefsharp. Does anyone know how to disable flags on cefsharp or any other workaround?

Comment: If you are using asp Net Core you can integrate your site directly into CefSharp using https://github.com/amaitland/Chromium.AspNetCore.Bridge You can then use a domain name rather than localhost and avoid CORS. As for the flag, it might be possible that you can use the --disable-features command line argument, would need to look up the corresponding feature key(string) in the chromium source.

Comment: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:content/public/common/content_features.cc;drc=cc56431a98152461ad58cf220ea03f4098f7008c;l=124

Answer (score 2):

I disabled "BlockInsecurePrivateNetworkRequests" feature as suggested by @amaitland and it worked.

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-features", "BlockInsecurePrivateNetworkRequests");
CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. add to Startup.cs
    `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

   ```
    {   services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
     }
   ```
2. add in `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)      app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());`
3. add to Controller.cs file
   `[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]`