# How to allow Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network with an NodeJS / Express webserver?

Tags: node.js, express, cors, http-headers, private-network-access

I have a intranet webserver.  It has no certs of any kind and is accessed via http.  It is technically a public IP but has no public routing.

On this webserver, I have a single page application that needs to call an https api nodejs/express endpoint on a different server (that I also control). I just had to add the cors library and 'use' it:
`app.use(cors())`
This worked a month or so back.

Now, when I do this, I get the following error:

> The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in
> more-private address space `private`.

Searching, brought me here: [Chrome CORS error on request to localhost dev server from remote site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534759/chrome-cors-error-on-request-to-localhost-dev-server-from-remote-site) which effectively says "make your server https".

Additional answers indicate that adding a header: `Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network: true` would be all that is needed.   This is backed up by the documentation here: [https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/#:~:text=The%20Access%2DControl%2DRequest%2D,safely%20shared%20with%20external%20networks](https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/#:%7E:text=The%20Access%2DControl%2DRequest%2D,safely%20shared%20with%20external%20networks) indicating:

> The Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network indicates that a resource can
> be safely shared with external networks.

I've tried this on the api server by adding

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network", "true")
    next();
})
```

right after my previously-added `app.use(cors())` line.

This leaves me with:

```
const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors())
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network", "true")
    next();
})
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api', jobRouter);
```

This doesn't remove the error.

What needs to be done to allow my intranet non-http server to access an https server?  I control both sides.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is a hack until [this pr](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/pull/274/) is merged.

Essentially, you can add this snippet **before** cors middleware is added. the ordering of middleware is important.

```
app.use(function setCommonHeaders(req, res, next) {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network", "true");
  next();
});

// this has to come after
controlAPI.use(require("cors")({ credentials: true }));
```